# Convert Input text Value to a two digit decimal Number with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a Input Text Box with id=num. I give it a value 32.5687. I want to convert it to a Number like this 32.57. I tried the following Code that returns 32.57 then I test it's type with typeof() method that says it's a string not a Number.

```
$(documnet).ready(function(){
    $nmuber = $("#num").val();
    $number = parseFloat($number).toFixed(2);
    alert(typeof($number));
});
```

What is my wrong or what would be the correct process to convert the text input value to a two digit decimal Number?

Comment: This is expected behaviour - `toFixed()` returns a string.

Comment: `$nmuber` is a typo

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typos, this is expected behaviour; `toFixed()` returns a string. If you'd prefer to retain the rounded value as a float use `Math.round()`:

```js
number = Math.round(parseFloat('32.5687') * 100) / 100;
console.log(number);
console.log(typeof(number));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var num = 32.5687;
    var n = num.toFixed(2);
    n = parseFloat(n);
    alert(typeof(n));
```

toFixed() will just format the string. You need to use parseFloat() with combination of toFixed(). A simplified example as above.

As @Rory rightly commented - Be aware that calling toFixed() on a string causes an implicit type coercion which may not give you the result you expect in all cases.

Comment: Be aware that calling `toFixed()` on a string causes an implicit type coercion which may not give you the result you expect in all cases

Comment: I guess OP should be aware of handling the coercions. The answer is specifically to the problem mentioned. But I will update your comment in.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    var numb = parseFloat($("#num").val());
    numb = Math.round(numb * 100) / 100
    alert(numb);
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uucana91/)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery .val() function will always return string for a single element selected. You have to parseFloat explicitly to use it in your code.

Comment: OP is already using `parseFloat()`. This doesn't answer the question.